# Webpack: Different (Define Plugin) settings per entry point

Tags: webpack

For some of my bundle files I would like to build different versions (for example one with admin functionality and one without).

It seems the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) is usually used for this kind of thing, but there are also loaders like the [if-loader](https://github.com/friskfly/if-loader) or the [ifdef-loader](https://github.com/nippur72/ifdef-loader) available.

Now the problem is that they all seem to share a configuration among all entry points. I would need a way to set a different configuration (like `{with_admin_mode: true}` and `{with_admin_mode: false}`) for the different entry points.

I though of putting the configuration at the top of the actual entry point JS files, but I don't know how to correctly create a global variable across all modules that will be detected as `true == false` and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I meant to write providePlugin, not definePlugin. DefinePlugin will replace the variable in your code directly and will not create a global.

You can use providePlugin to set a global config variable from a module file that you have created:

in your webpack config:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'config': 'config'
  })
  ...
],
resolve: {
  alias: { 'config':  path.resolve(__dirname, './config') },
  extensions: ['.js']
}
```

and `config` will be set as a global to the exports of a `config.js` file.

You can then access and modify this global in your different entry points. For example, you could do `config.with_admin_mode = true;` in entry1.js and `config.with_admin_mode = false;` in entry2.js.

Another solution would be to set the global variable on the window directly from your modules, e.g.  `window.with_admin_mode = true;`

Comment: After reading this 10 times I still don't understand what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. Even when I put `config.with_admin_mode = false;` and `if (config.with_admin_mode === true) ` in the same file, the `if` block is converted to `!0===t.with_admin_mode&&console.log("foo")` but it's not removed.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you want the block to be removed. In that case it might be best to use definePlugin and webpack's multi-compiler mode. Set the exports of your webpack config to an array of configs and change the definePlugin and entries properties. Check out this example: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler

Comment: That doesn't help if you have code that runs during initalization. Since you're required to place imports before code, the common code will run before you have a chance to assign anything in `entry.js`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to look at [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge#smart-merging) – **Smart Merging** should help you to solve your case.

It can help to make dynamic configuration with specific entry points, plugins and what ever you want that would be depends on some variable on env.

Good practice to split configuration into different files.
You can make some common configuration with the same things through all entry points, e.g loaders and then make custom configurations for `with_admin_mode` and `without_admin_node` modes.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Are you suggesting I should just make multiple configs? That's what I wanted to avoid because they share a great deal of settings and it would probably break CommonsChunkPlugin.